# Transition function of line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic curve over $\mathbb C$ and fix a closed point $p\in X$. I want to calculate the transition functions of the line bundle associated the sheaf $\mathcal O(p)$.

I know that this line bundle is trivial over $X-\{p\}$, so it has only one transition function. But I can't see how to calculate it?

many thanks

Comment: It should be given by an uniformizer of $\mathcal{O}_p$ on a neighborhood of p